# Add jetpack compose to existing project

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an existing android studio project and I want to use jetpack compose in my project. The documentation says how to create a new project with jetpack compose, but how to use it with existing projects?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Jetpack compose requires  a `minSdkVersion` of at least 21. So add/update the following in your `app/build.gradle` file

```
android{ 
   //...
   defaultConfig {       
      minSdkVersion 21
      targetSdkVersion 29
      //...
   }
  //...
 }
```

Also you need to use [Android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)  (from canary channel) in order to use jetpack-compose with the latest features.

### Easiest method for existing projects

**Step 1:**

In project window, `right click on the package you want to include the compose activity -> compose -> Empty compose activity`.

or

```
File -> new -> compose -> Empty compose activity.
```

**Step 2**

A dialog window will appear. Fill up the required fields and click `Finish`.

[image]

That's all.

---

### Manual configuration for existing projects

**Step 1:**
Use latest version of kotlin and gradle plugins in your `project/build.gradle` file.

Example:

```
buildscript {
     ext {
    compose_version = '1.3.1'
}

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha02'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

In your `project/app/build.gradle`, add the following

```
android{ 
   //...
   defaultConfig {       
      minSdkVersion 21
      targetSdkVersion 30
      //...
   }
  //...

  kotlinOptions {
       jvmTarget = "1.8"
        useIR = true
  }

  buildFeatures {
    compose true
  }
  composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.32'
}
}


dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-beta1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
}
```

**Step 2:**
Add the compose activity into your manifest file.

```
 <application      
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     <!-- ... -->
     >
     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   
      <!-- ... -->
  </application>
```

**Step 3:**

Create the jetpack-compose Activity.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.Composable
import androidx.ui.foundation.Text
import androidx.ui.core.setContent
import androidx.ui.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.ui.tooling.preview.Preview

class MainComposeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                Greeting("Android")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

**That's all. Happy coding :)**

Comment: Please help, i have an existing android project that is coded in Java and XML can I follow these steps that you mentioned?

Answer (score 4):

Just follow the [official setup](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#add-compose).
Add in your `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.4.0'
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildFeatures {
        // Enables Jetpack Compose for this module
        compose true
    }
    ...

    // Set both the Java and Kotlin compilers to target Java 8.

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        useIR = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-alpha01"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // You also need to include the following Compose toolkit dependencies.
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-alpha01'
    ...
}
```

Also starting with **`1.0.0-alpha01`** you can combine Compose with your existing UI design.

Add in your layout the [**`ComposeView`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/ComposeView):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  
    <TextView/>

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your `Activity`, set the `ComposeView` using the XML ID, and call **`setContent()`** to use Compose:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_std)
    .apply {
        findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).setContent {
           MaterialTheme () {
              Text(text = "Compose text", style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2)
           }
         }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you able to get the old XML layout previewer to work for xml files with ComposeViews in them?
On my android studio (4.2) the previewer fails with an IllegalStateException because the ComposeView doesn't have a ViewTreeLifecycleOwner attached to it, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

In your `root level` build.gradle Add compose version variable inside `buildscript`

```
ext {
    compose_version = '1.0.1'
}
```

[image]

Now in your `app level` build.gradle add buildFeatures and composeOptions
inside your android { } block

```
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
}
```

and in your depenendencies

```
// Jetpack dependencies
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
// Jetpack debug dependencies
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
```

[image]

Now you can start using compose in your existing/new project

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        // your compose code goes here
    }
  }
}
```