# Why empty compose activity not found in Android Studio Beta5?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I recently installed android studio beta 5 to learn jetpack compose but to create a new project empty compose activity is not available, can any one help me.I am using android studio in mac[image: I have attached the image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add jetpack compose to existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61559352/add-jetpack-compose-to-existing-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should download the android studio arctic fox

overview:

1. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup
2. [image]

Answer (score 19):

On **Latest Android Studio** it's by default compose activity.

The "**Empty Activity**" will create a new **empty material3 compose** the project, which should work the same as the "Empty-Compose-Activity" template. You can find more info in the [official release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases)

Answer (score 1):

**Currently** in AS 4.2 Beta5 the compose activity is **not** available.

As described in the [guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup):

> you should download the latest canary version of **[Android Studio Preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Android Studio Canary is installed.